# How to loop python script over at end

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have the following test script I am playing with.

```
import time

year = time.strftime('%Y')
name = input('What is your name? ')
dob = input('What is your DOB ')
age = int(year) - int(dob)

print(f'{name}, You are {age} years old.')
```

How do I start this script over after it prints out the last statement? Sorry for such a silly question, I have been looking everywhere but cannot find anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm

Comment: I saw while loops, but does that make sense here? Because there is not a condition, just at the end of the page.

Comment: If you know how many times you want to run this code, use for loops ; if it mainly depends on a condition, use while loop. To run your code forever, do `while True:`. Otherwise, please add more details and expected behavior

Comment: The while True worked, I appreciate it! Please submit an answwer so I can accept it. Thanks @ted

Comment: @Kevin , you should search better. This is a basic thing about loops, you should improve your algorithm ability or take a good tutorial.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL Did me asking this question ruin your day?

Comment: No, it didnt. But here is [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL This was a good question. I was not sure what kind of loop to use. I researched and could not figure it out. Now in the future people can reference this question if they have the same issues. Thanks.

Comment: Okey, but notice that this question is duplicate.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL You had to involve yourself in something so petty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203615/discussion-between-ekrem-dncel-and-kevinm1990112qwq).

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL I'm sure there are 1000's of duplicates here. But find one written out exactly like mine, Ill pay you 5 bucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how many times you want to run this code, use `for` loops ; if it mainly depends on a condition, use `while` loop. To run your code forever, do `while True:`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `for` statement, this will also allow you to specify the number of times you would like to run this.

```
import time
n = 2

for _ in range(n):
    year = time.strftime('%Y')
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    dob = input('What is your DOB ')
    age = int(year) - int(dob)

    print(f'{name}, You are {age} years old.')
```

If you would like to run forever then use `while` loops.

```
import time

while True:
    year = time.strftime('%Y')
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    dob = input('What is your DOB ')
    age = int(year) - int(dob)

    print(f'{name}, You are {age} years old.')
```